# How to get application file path as string C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have a function called "ExePath"

```
string exepath()
{
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
return std::string(buffer);
}
```

This returns the path of the application.
Later, I try to copy the application to another place.

```
CopyFile(exepath, "C:\\Example\\Example.exe", FALSE);
```

When compiling I get the following error:

```
[Error] cannot convert 'std::string' to 'LPCSTR' for argument '1' to 'WINBOOL CopyFileA(LPCSTR, LPCSTR, WINBOOL)'
```

I take this as it cant use the string as a string. What?
Basically I am trying to find the path that the application has been executed and copy it to another place. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `std::string` and `LPCSTR` are two completely different types. The compiler's error message couldn't be more clear. You should spend some time studying the difference between `std::string`, a C++ class, and C-style strings, and how to convert between the two.

Comment: also, `exepath` needs to be called as `exepath.c_str()`

Answer (score 1):

`LPCSTR` is a Long Pointer to a Const STRing(`const char *`), `string::c_str` function will return the corresponding `const char *` to your `string` class.

So the first parameter should be as `exepath.c_str()`.

```
CopyFile(exepath.c_str(), "C:\\Example\\Example.exe", FALSE);
```